# Array of images inside cell?

Tags: tabulator

I was wondering if it's possible for a  tabulator cell to display an array of images, I tried looking at the docs or other similar questions but I didn't manage to achieve much.

I'm guessing it has something to do with a custom formatter.

Suppose that I have a json array that indicates the location of the image, how would I go around putting those into a cell?

While that would be easy to achieve in html using img tags, I just can't get my head around how to do that in a custom formatter in Tabulator.

An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today and I found a solution.

First, here's my data :

```
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, picture:""},
    {id:2, picture:"img0.jpg"},
    {id:3, picture:"img1.jpg;img2.jpg;img3.jpg;img4.jpg"}
];
```

And here's the code I used to generate the column:

```
{
    title: "Photos", field: "picture", 
    formatter: function (cell, formatterParams) {
        var div = $('<div>');
        var all_pictures = cell.getValue().split(';');
        for (var i=0; i<all_pictures.length; i++) {
            var img = $("<img src='" + all_pictures[i] + "'/>");

            // If you want to give your pictures a fixed width
            img.width(parseInt(formatterParams.width));


            div.append(img);

            // Adapt the height of the cell to the height of the images
            img.on("load", function(){
                cell.getRow().normalizeHeight();
            })
        }
        return div[0];
    }, 
    formatterParams:{width:"50px"},
    variableHeight:true
}
```

Basically, for each picture you have to create a html img and put your images inside one single div (the function must return at most one html element, so you can't just return several `<img/>`). I used jQuery but this method works also in vanilla js. Also I stored the sources in a string that I splited into an array, but the code should work similarly with a json array.

The `img.on('load' ... )` part is not necessary, however without it the height of the cell won't adapt to the images and thus they may not appear entirely.

Hope this helps!